# Arabic characters are not displaying correctly in the generated vCard (vcf file via php) in outlook

Tags: php, outlook, vcf-vcard

I have a php code to generate vCard and download it as vcf file to open in Outlook. It is working fine for English characters but when I try changing the firstname or any other data to Arabic, the generated vCard opens in outlook with wrong or dummy characters in outlook. I have even tried changing to different charsets but I didn't get any success. What could be the issue?

I also want to share this vCard through social media like whatsapp, email, messenger through php. How can I achieve this as well?

I searched a lot online for solutions but couldn't find one. Please help me.

I have two files for generating vCard namely vcard.php and vcardexp.inc.php which are as follows,

vcard.php

```
<?php

    include("vcardexp.inc.php"); 

    $test = new vcardexp;

    $test->setValue("firstName", "ماكس");
    $test->setValue("lastName", "Mustermann");
    $test->setValue("organisation", "Mustermann Holding GmbH");
    $test->setValue("tel_work", "01234/567890");
    $test->setValue("tel_home", "069/0123456");
    $test->setValue("tel_pref", "069/0123456");
    $test->setValue("url", "http://www.foo.bar");
    $test->setValue("email_internet", "max@foo.bar");
    $test->setValue("email_pref", "max@foo.bar");
    $test->setValue("street_home", "Musterstrasse 1");
    $test->setValue("postal_home", "12345");
    $test->setValue("city_home", "Musterstadt");
    $test->setValue("country_home", "Musterland");
    $test->copyPicture("test.jpg");

    $test->getCard();

?>
```

vcardexp.inc.php

```
<?php

    class vcardexp
    /* Bibliothek zur Genegierung von digitalen Visitenkarten */
    {

        //Deklarationen
        var $fields = array();

        var $allowed = array(
            "language",
            "firstName", "additionalName", "lastName", "title", "addon", "organisation", "note",
            "tel_work", "tel_home", "tel_cell", "tel_car", "tel_isdn", "tel_pref", "fax_work", "fax_home",
            "street_work", "city_work", "postal_work", "country_work", "street_home", "city_home", "postal_home", "country_home",
            "url", "email_internet", "email_pref", "picture"
        );



        function setValue($setting, $value)
        /* Wert eintragen */
        {

            //Ist die Einstellung in der Liste erlaubter Einstellungen?
            if(in_array($setting, $this->allowed))
            {
                //Ja, setze Einstellung und Wert
                $this->fields[$setting] = $value;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Nein
                return false;
            }

        }



        function copyPicture($path)
        /* Foto-Import */
        {
            //Ist die Datei vorhanden?
            if(is_file($path))
            {
                //Ja, beziehe die Bildgroesse
                $temp = getimagesize($path);

                //Ist das Bild nicht groesser als 185x185?
                if($temp[0] <= 185 && $temp[1] <= 185)
                {
                    //Ja, berechne base64-Code und setze
                    $this->fields["picture"] = base64_encode(file_get_contents ($path));
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Nein, es ist zu gross
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Nein, Datei ist nicht vorhanden
                return false;
            }
        }



        function setPicture($value)
        /* Bild direkt als BASE64-Code setzen, NOT RECOMMENDED */
        {
            $this->fields["picture"] = $value;
            return true;
        }



        function dump()
        /* Dump ausgeben */
        {

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->fields);
            echo "</pre>";
            return true;

        }



        function getCard()
        /* Visitenkarte generieren */
        {

            //Header ausgeben
            header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8');
            $card  = "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
            $card .= "VERSION:2.1\n";

            //Sprache und Vor- und Nachname setzen
            if($this->fields["language"] == "") { $this->fields["language"] = "ar"; }
            $card .= "N;LANGUAGE=".$this->fields["language"].":".$this->fields["lastName"].";".$this->fields["firstName"]."\n";

            //Anzeigenamen setzen
            $card .= "FN:".$this->fields["firstName"]." ".$this->fields["lastName"]."\n";

            //Firma und Titel setzen, falls vorhanden
            if(isset($this->fields["organisation"]))
            {
                $card .= "ORG:".$this->fields["organisation"]."\n";
            }
            if(isset($this->fields["title"]))
            {
                $card .= "TITLE:".$this->fields["title"]."\n";
            }

            //zw  vn nicht gesetzt
            //zusatz nicht gesetzt
            //note nicht gesetzt
            //nur eine home tel
            //nur zwei mails
            //bug isset ==> array mit erlaubten feldern
            //Check fields

            //Telefon- und Faxnummern setzen

                if(isset($this->fields["tel_work"])) { $card .= "TEL;WORK;VOICE:".$this->fields["tel_work"]."\n"; } //Arbeit
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_home"])) { $card .= "TEL;HOME;VOICE:".$this->fields["tel_home"]."\n"; } //Privat
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_cell"])) { $card .= "TEL;CELL;VOICE:".$this->fields["tel_cell"]."\n"; }     //Handy
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_car"])) { $card .= "TEL;CAR;VOICE:".$this->fields["tel_car"]."\n"; }        //Autotelefon
                if(isset($this->fields["fax_work"])) { $card .= "TEL;WORK;FAX:".$this->fields["fax_work"]."\n"; }   //Fax-Arbeit
                if(isset($this->fields["fax_home"])) { $card .= "TEL;HOME;FAX:".$this->fields["fax_home"]."\n"; }   //Fax-Privat
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_home"])) { $card .= "TEL;HOME:".$this->fields["tel_home"]."\n"; }       //Privat, Kopie von obriger Angabe
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_isdn"])) { $card .= "TEL;ISDN:".$this->fields["tel_isdn"]."\n"; }           //ISDN
                if(isset($this->fields["tel_pref"])) { $card .= "TEL;PREF:".$this->fields["tel_pref"]."\n"; }           //Standard-Nummer



            //Adressen setzen

                //Arbeit
                if(isset($this->fields["street_work"]) && isset($this->fields["city_work"]) && isset($this->fields["postal_work"]) && isset($this->fields["country_work"]))
                {
                    $card .= "ADR;WORK;PREF:;;".$this->fields["street_work"].";".$this->fields["city_work"].";;".$this->fields["postal_work"].";".$this->fields["country_work"]."\n";
                    $card .= "LABEL;WORK;PREF;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:".$this->fields["street_work"]."=0D=0A=\n";
                    $card .= "=0D=0A=\n";
                    $card .= $this->fields["postal_work"]." ".$this->fields["city_work"]."\n";
                }

                //Privat
                if(isset($this->fields["street_home"]) && isset($this->fields["city_home"]) && isset($this->fields["postal_home"]) && isset($this->fields["country_home"]))
                {
                    $card .= "ADR;HOME;PREF:;;".$this->fields["street_home"].";".$this->fields["city_home"].";;".$this->fields["postal_home"].";".$this->fields["country_home"]."\n";
                    $card .= "LABEL;HOME;PREF;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:".$this->fields["street_home"]."=0D=0A=\n";
                    $card .= "=0D=0A=\n";
                    $card .= $this->fields["postal_home"]." ".$this->fields["city_home"]."\n";
                }



            //URL und E-Mails setzen

                if(isset($this->fields["url"])) { $card .= "URL;WORK:".$this->fields["url"]."\n"; }                     //Homepage setzen
                if(isset($this->fields["email_pref"])) { $card .= "EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:".$this->fields["email_pref"]."\n"; }        //Standard-Mail
                if(isset($this->fields["email_internet"])) { $card .= "EMAIL;INTERNET:".$this->fields["email_internet"]."\n"; }     //Zusatz-Mail



            //Foto hinzufuegen, falls vorhanden
            if(isset($this->fields["picture"]))
            {
                $card .= "PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:\n";
                $card .= $this->fields["picture"];
                $card .= "\n\n\n";
            }

            //TODO: REV?

            //Ende setzen
            $card .= "END:VCARD";

            //Karte ausgeben und String loeschen
            echo $card;
            $card = "";

        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the meta tag to your HTML code, if you are using any templates you can add,

```
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
```

In your code, try making this change in the dump(),

```
function dump()
    /* Dump ausgeben */
    {
        echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>"; //HERE
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->fields);
        echo "</pre>";
        return true;

    }
```

That should work, I was able to make it work locally this way.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Now I am getting some other characters than before.

Comment: I even tried using iconv function with different character sets but that is also not solving my issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry I had forgot to mention you might need to set the charset on the HTML side, I have edited my previous answer please check..

Comment: I tried your updated answer but no success. I am getting Arabic characters as Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã˜Â®Ã˜Â·Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â¨, Ã˜Â£Ã˜Â¨Ã™Âˆ Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã™Â‚Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â³Ã™Â… Ã˜Â´Ã™ÂˆÃ™Â‚Ã™ÂŠ

Comment: If I remove utf8 encoding I get Arabic characters as Ø£Ø¨Ùˆ Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø´ÙˆÙ‚ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø®Ø·Ù

Comment: Please remove the previously set utf8_encode()
Fromt this, `$this->fields[$setting] = utf8_encode($value);`
to
`$this->fields[$setting] = $value;`

Comment: Can you send me your local files that works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CHARSET parameter to the appropriate vCard properties may help.  For example:

```
$card .= "FN;CHARSET=utf-8:" ...
```

Or, you may need to explicitly tell PHP to output the string in UTF-8.  PHP only changes its character encoding when outputting HTML.

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I didn't succeed. Now the Arabic Characters are being displayed as Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã˜Â®Ã˜Â·Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â¨, Ã˜Â£Ã˜Â¨Ã™Âˆ Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã™Â‚Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â³Ã™Â… Ã˜Â´Ã™ÂˆÃ™Â‚Ã™ÂŠ

Comment: If I remove utf8 encoding I get Arabic characters as Ø£Ø¨Ùˆ Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø´ÙˆÙ‚ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø®Ø·Ù

Comment: Can you send me some sample files?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem and the solution tasted for IOS 8 and higher is :

in the class file REPLACE under getCard() function:

```
            header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; CHARSET=utf-8;');

        $card  = "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
        $card .= "VERSION:2.1\n";

        //Sprache und Vor- und Nachname setzen
        if($this->fields["language"] == "") { $this->fields["language"] = "AR"; }
        $card .= "N;"."CHARSET=utf-8:".$this->fields["lastName"].";".$this->fields["firstName"]."\n";
```

It works very well for me.